# How to get data inside child inside another child - firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from Firebase. It looks like this

[image]

Can you give me a solution ?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and about [providing an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing what you've tried and where you're stuck, it's going to be hard to give a better answer than what the Firebase documentation already provides: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write.

Comment: Which data are you trying to get? Please respond using @name

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce array of incremented integer, use more unique incremented ID provided by firebase, so you can access the data using that unique incremented ID "KdfHHgJYggAyp-ZbFkP" looks like this

```
String name=dataSnapshot.child("KdfHHgJYggAyp-ZbFkP").child("name").getValue(String.class).toString() ;
```

In your case you can use

```
String name=dataSnapshot.child("1").child("name").getValue(String.class).toString() ;
String name=dataSnapshot.child("2").child("name").getValue(String.class).toString() ;
```